# The image cannot be displayed because of errors

Tags: php, image

Our online LMS provides certificates when a course is successfully completed. This has been working for years. Now, out of the blue, I'm getting "The image cannot be displayed because of errors". I cannot reproduce this on my development computer. My host server is running PHP 7.1.33; Apache; Linux OS. I refresh the browser window two or three times and it finally displays.

Below is the code. It takes a png image of a blank certificate and adds the pertinent info for the individual and class. I don't think this is a code issue but I've included it anyway although I've removed much of the overlay code as it's irrelevant to the issue.

Any insights as to what the hey is going on would be appreciated.

```
<?php
    include("../../_includes/path.php");
    include("../../_includes/dbconn.php");
    include("stauthorization.php");


    ob_clean();

    // Set the content-type
    header('Content-Type: image/png');


    // Create the image

    $im = imagecreatefrompng($xpath1 . "/account_center/distributor/piccexcellence_cert_1.png");



    $angle = 90;
    $rotated = imagerotate($im, $angle, 0);


    imagepng($rotated);
    imagedestroy($im);


?>
```

Comment: There is no error handling at all.

Answer (score 0):

I moved our site over to a newer server and ran into this problem again. Turns out it was an SSL issue. Once I installed a valid security certificate on the host this problem was fixed.